# Populating values to a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Off lately I have taken up the task to understand and learn C. Right now I was learning about structures and pointer arrays. I have a problem. I want to populate a pointer array with values. Below is my code:

```
           struct profile_t 
          {
           unsigned char length;
           unsigned char type;
           unsigned char *data;
          };

          typedef struct profile_datagram_t
         {
          unsigned char src[4];
          unsigned char dst[4];
          unsigned char ver;
          unsigned char n;
          struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];       
         } header;

          header outObj;

         int j =0;
         int i =0;

      outObj.profiles[j].data = malloc(10);

      for(i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
         if (j=0)
             {
           outObj.profiles[j][i] = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
         }
         else 
             {
        j=1;
         }
      }

      for(i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
        if (j=1)
            {
           outObj.profiles[j][i] = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
        }
      }
```

Is the above approach the way to go or am I completely offtrack. MAXPROFILES is 2 (which means only 0 and 1).

Comment: Please indent your code sanely.

Comment: "MAXPROFILES is just 1 (which means only 0 and 1)": **no**, it means only 0: `outObj.profiles[0]` is valid; `outObj.profiles[1]` is not valid.

Comment: @pmg: thanks, so if MAXPROFILES is 2, then outObj.profiles[1] is valid. And the way I am initialzing the element...is that the proper way to go??

Comment: No, you can't do it that way. You'll have to use another loop.

Comment: @anon: I do not think so, at least I have never ever seen this kind of initializer... see my code snippet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign like this

```
outObj.profiles[j][i] = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
```

`outObj.profiles[j]` is profile_t instance.
`outObj.profiles[j].data` is char*.
I suppose that you want to assign that integers to data.
First of all you should allocate memory for both j values.

```
outObj.profiles[0].data = malloc(10);
outObj.profiles[1].data = malloc(10);
```

I suggest you to replace your code with loops with something like this

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    outObj.profiles[0].data[i] = i+1;
    outObj.profiles[1].data[i] = i+1;
}
```

The result is same but it is much cleaner to read and understand.

Comment: Was the repetition of the lines in the last code piece a copy and paste error or did you mean to use `0` and `1` respectively, instead of 'j`?

Comment: @Rudy it was old copy-paste ;-) Fixed it.

Comment: @user it depends on the way you get these numbers. If they are stored anywhere you should copy them one-by-one. If you are getting them as a result of some function you should call it inside of the cycle and generate numbers one-by-one either....

Comment: @tyz: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but as a curious learner of "C", suppose instead of 2 MAXPROFILES, i had 50, don't you think it is cumbersome to write outOBJ.profiles[0], then [1]...[50]...won't a loop be beneficial???

Comment: @user Yes, if there are a lot of objects loop is a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Or in short:

```
#define DATALENGTH 10

uint actProfile = 0;
uint actData = 0;



for( actProfile = 0; actProfile < MAXPROFILES; ++actProfile )
{
    outObj.profiles[actProfile].data = malloc(DATALENGTH);

    //skip check if malloc was successfull...

    for ( actData = 0; actData < DATALENGTH; ++actData )
    {
      outObj.profiles[actProfile].data[actData] = actData +1;
    }
}
```

Comment: :If the data can be anything...not necessarily 1,2,3,4,.....then my code should work right??

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate space for `outObj.profiles[1].data`.

The sequence of numbers (`1 2 ... 10`) is a syntax error. You may want to use the loop variable

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    outObj.profiles[0][i] = i + 1;
}
```